# How do small companies access user transaction data?

Tags: best-practice, web-crawling

I am not sure if this is relevant in this forum but I have always wonder how companies like Retention Science, Factual and several other smaller companies seem to be able to get transaction data or customer product viewing records with ease. This kind of amaze me as I thought these data are hard to come by. Do they buy them from other companies or do they actually have clever algorithm to crawl the data?